# Duvida Rotulo de Coluna - Seaborn Python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Estou com uma Dúvida ao Plotar um grafico no Seaborn, aonde o rotulo do Eixo de Coluna fica muito grande
[image: Como está agora]

Porem, gostaria de "quebrar" essa linha em 2, ou 3 Linhas, para ficar menor a caixa do rótulo e dar maior destaque para o grafico

Como posso fazer isso

```
pais = base_depara['Dono'].unique()
print(pais)

for pai in pais:
    img_email = base_depara.loc[base_depara['Dono'] == pai, ['grupo','Tt_casos', 'criados_d3', 'criados_d1']]
    
    altura = []
    for i in img_email['Tt_casos']:
       altura.append(i)
    posicao = []
    for i in range(len(img_email['grupo'])): 
       posicao.append(i)
   #criando uma figure, axes, alterando tamanho
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
    #criando o gráfico de barras
    sns.barplot(x=img_email['grupo'], y=img_email['Tt_casos'], ax=ax, data=img_email,  palette='RdPu_r')
    #adicionando título
    ax.set_title("quantidade x ano", fontdict={'fontsize':15})
    #mudando e nome e tamanho do label x
    ax.set_xlabel('Anos', fontdict={'fontsize':14})
    #mudando tamanho do label eixo y
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    #mudando tamanho dos labels dos ticks
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
    #aumentando espessura linha inferior
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2.5)
    #remoção dos outros três axis
    for axis in ['top', 'right', 'left']:
       ax.spines[axis].set_color(None)
    #remoção dos ticks
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelleft=False, left=None)                  
    #Colocando a quantidade em cada barra
    for i in range(len(img_email)):
       ax.text(x=posicao[i]-0.2, y=altura[i]+0.2, s=str(altura[i]),   
               fontsize=15)
    #otimizar espaço da figure
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    fig.tight_layout();
```

Comment: pode disponibilizar os dados ou criar um MWE?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que existam várias maneiras, mas infelizmente parece que o seaborn não implementa isso.

Substituindo espaço por `\n` seria uma opção

```
ml_labels = [label.replace(' ', '\n') for label in labels]
```

Parece que o `textwrap` também funciona

```
from textwrap import wrap

ml_labels = ['\n'.join(wrap(label, 15)) for label in labels]
```

**Nota**: isso irá cortar o label no 15º caracter

Parece que o [dexplot](https://dexplo.org/dexplot) também faz isso, mas não testei.